# Python Falcon filtering through URL

Tags: python, api, falcon

I have a small API that i'm working on, everything works ok, all my requests do what they are supposed to but when I try to filter results through the URL query for some reason it works for id but not for device field.

```
def on_get(self, req, resp):
    """Handles GET requests"""
    if req.get_param("id"):
        result = {'location': r.db(PROJECT_DB).table(PROJECT_TABLE).get(req.get_param("id")).run(db_connection)}

    elif req.get_param("device"):
        result = {'location': r.db(PROJECT_DB).table(PROJECT_TABLE).get(req.get_param("device")).run(db_connection)}

    else:
        location = r.db(PROJECT_DB).table(PROJECT_TABLE).run(db_connection)
        result = {'locations': [i for i in location]}
    resp.body = json.dumps(result)
```

example `http://localhost:8000/location?id=(some random id)` this will work

but if i do `http://localhost:8000/location?device=(some device)` this will not work, returns null

So could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? or better yet if anyone knows a better way to filter using the URL?

Note: I am using rethinkdb

EDIT:

This is what I have normally:

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": "4bf4b94f-747a-42db-9d54-a8399d995025",
      "location": "gps coords",
      "device": "Device 2"
    },
    {
      "id": "b5cce561-37d2-42e7-86e4-a31c008b0af2",
      "location": "gps coords",
      "device": "Device 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "bebba7cf-710c-4ee8-ad69-2d58174d4e02",
      "location": "gps coords",
      "device": "Device 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "e928f84b-60ff-40f3-b839-920bc99e5480",
      "location": "gps coords",
      "device": "Device1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Filtering by id works ok, but not by device which is weird

Comment: Obviously there's nothing with that `device=(some device)`. Or did you put logging in your app to verify that `result` is something different than null?

Comment: Have you checked the types in the request and the data you pull from the locations query? probably there is a mismatch there

Comment: yes I have, and there is nothing to indicate a missmatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem, the reason why it did not war was because rethinkdb only gets via primary key on the get query

```
result = {'location': r.db(PROJECT_DB).table(PROJECT_TABLE).get(req.get_param("device")).run(db_connection)}
```

so what I should have done was to filter the results by what I wanted like this and it would have worked

```
result = {'location': list(r.db(PROJECT_DB).table(PROJECT_TABLE).filter({'device': param}).run(db_connection))}
```

Thanks for the help everyone and hope this answer helps.